# Batch file that launch commands in CMDER

Tags: batch-file, cmd, conemu, cmder

I need to find a way to execute commands in bat file via cmder.
When I put `start -cur_console:s1T50H -cur_console:d:C:\Users\MY\Path\` **inside cmder** its open another shell as i want.
What should I do to make it happen when I execute my bat file?

My .bat file right now:

```
@echo off 
start C:\Users\PATH\TO\CMDER\FOLDER\cmder.exe

pause
```

What should I write after start the cmder?

Comment: Anything you add to the batch file after starting `cmder.exe` is going to execute in the context of the batch file. `start` just creates a new process. Does `cmder` take any arguments? A script file name to run perhaps?